# curl shell command always returns error status 0 - even when fails on input errors

Tags: shell, shell-script, curl

Example: trying to upload a non existing file - `curl -d @no-real-file http://google.com | echo $?` - returns 0.

How can I make curl fail on input errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `curl -f`

```
-f, --fail  (HTTP) Fail silently (no output at all) on server errors. 
This is mostly done to better enable scripts etc to better deal with failed attempts. 
In normal cases when a HTTP server  fails  to  deliver  a  document,  it returns 
an HTML document stating so (which often also describes why and more). This flag 
will prevent curl from outputting that and return error 22.

This method is not fail-safe and there are occasions where non-successful response 
codes will slip through, especially when authentication is involved (response codes 
401 and 407).
```

If `-f` is used, `curl` will return `22` for the following command

```
curl -f -d @no-real-file http://google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you asked for, but you could simply do a quick check to see if the file exists beforehand:

```
[ -f $somefile ] && curl -d $somefile blah blah
```

Comment: The @no-real-file is just an example. I think there can be other scenarios as well.